# Codeigniter RestFul library Prevent SQL injections

Tags: web-services, security, codeigniter, rest, sql-injection

I'm using codeigniter philsturgeon Restful library to develop Web-services. So How can I prevent SQL injections from webservices? Is there any library in codeigniter to Prevent SQL injections from restful webservices?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with the database class in CI?

Answer (score 1):

You prevent SQL injection by:

1. escaping any literal values you inject into an SQL query;
2. (way better) using database interfaces that do not require you to inject literal values into an SQL query, such as parameterised queries.

CodeIgniter's Database library gives you both of these:

1. `$this->db->query('SELECT x FROM y WHERE z='.$this->db->escape('value1'));`
2. (way better) `$this->db->query('SELECT x FROM y WHERE z=?', array('value1'));`

(Don't be fooled into thinking you can address SQL injection properly through input sanitisation.)

Comment: Option 2 works all the time. Option 1 can be vulnerable to multi-byte character attacks, depending on the encodings and charsets in use.